# How to add multiple properties in the character class \p in JS using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible in JS to separate somehow instructions in \p character class?
For instance, I want to match 1 cyrillic letter in upper case and trying to write something like
`let regexp = /\p{Lu sc=Cyrillic}/u;`

I didn't find any way to separate the instructions `Lu` and `sc=Cyrillic`. I've tried comma, semi-colon, space but nothing has helped.
Is there any correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using a lookahead assertion for one of the properties.

```
let regexp = /(?=\p{Lu})\p{sc=Cyrillic}/u;
```